# Integer polynomials and the integration on the unit circle

Tags: polynomials

Let $f (x) $ be a polynomial in $\mathbb {C}[x] $. Then, consider the value $I_f $ defined as $I_f:=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} |f (e^{ix})|^2 dx$. We can define this on any complex polynomial, but I'm interested in the case the coefficients are integers.

Question. Is there an integer coefficient polynomial $f\ne 0$ with $I_f <1$?

If the answer of Q is negative, can I take a lower bound larger than 0 of $I_f $ which depends only on the degree of $f $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|1-e^{x i}+({e^{x i}})^2|^2dx \approx 0.7$

Comment: Thanks! quite simpler than I guessed.